# CMake uses NASM for linking, which fails.

Tags: cmake, nasm

I have an assembler file I want to compile in one run. However, the following code fails:

```
enable_language(ASM_NASM)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_FLAGS "${CMAKE_ASM_NASM_FLAGS} -f bin")
add_executable(test test.s)
```

CMake first runs: `nasm -f bin -o test.s.o test.s`
And then: `nasm -f bin -o test test.s.o`
The last step fails as test.s.o is already a binary file.

My question is: How do I disable the first compilation step?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do, leitimmel. Disable the first compilation? But that's the one that works! `-f bin` is a legitimate output format, but it seems unlikely to be what you'd want in an environment that includes CMake. (more likely `-f elf32` or `-f elf64`?)

Comment: The second step would do the same. The problem is that it runs the command twice and I want to change that. I thought it might be better to disable the first one because its result has the wrong name (`.s.o`), but if that is not possible, the second one would also be ok. The output format is intended as I am programming a bootloader.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be a bug in nasm module for cmake. Cmake calls nasm for linking which is obviously wrong (that is why you see two calls to nasm). Hotfix is to set

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_LINK_EXECUTABLE "ld <FLAGS> <CMAKE_ASM_NASM_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
```

Comment: Actually `CMake` now warns that `Missing variable is: CMAKE_NASM_LINK_EXECUTABLE`. If say 2 executables are built one of which is `C` and the other one is `ASM_NASM` CMAKE does not produce such warning. So this seems the recommended way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved your problem, however I feel like I need to post here my solution just because that's the only mention of this problem and it doesn't seem to be solved by the only given answer.
Indeed, `nasm` can compile sources directly to `.bin` format (and that's really helpful for boot sectors). The problem is that `Cmake` doesn't seem to support single stage compilation and linking and it tries to link resulting `.bin` file, which is imposseible, so the execution fails no matter which linker we try to use.
The only solution that came to my mind was replacing `add_executable(NAME SOURCE)` with `add_library(NAME OBJECT SOURCE)`. Object libraris are not linked, so the file produced will be exactly what we are looking for.
And here is the complete solution:

```
enable_language(ASM_NASM)

set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT bin)
add_compile_options("$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:ASM_NASM>:-f bin>")

add_library(lib OBJECT core/boot/loader.asm)
```

The tricky part: the generated file will be hidden within `cmake` output dir. It sould be referenced with `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib>`.
Enjoy!